# Google Analytics URL Campaign Builder - Tracking Radio Campaigns?

Tags: google-analytics

Afternoon all...

I am getting ready to run some radio campaigns here in the coming weeks.
I will be sending visitors to www.example.com/superdeal

That URL is basically going to redirect to our main shopping site since it is pretty lengthy.

What i want to know is if Google URL Campaign Builder will properly track Radio campaigns in the Campaign tab in Analytics with a URL like this:

https://sale.example.com/?utm_source=Radio&utm_campaign=SuperDeal&utm_medium=radio

I wasn't sure if Radio was a valid source to track. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will work. I tried it with one of my Accounts:

[image]

You can see the Data in the Tab Source/Medium. You can also set up a Channel for this. So you see the data in the Acquisation-Channel-Tab.
Herefore go to Admin > Channel Settings > Channel Grouping > "+New Channel Grouping"